# Free and informed consent for medical test

Tags: medical, consent, south-africa

My company requires me to have life insurance for which I recently moved out of the provider's "free cover limit". Because of this I now have to submit to certain medical tests in order to have full cover.

In the document I received are the following lines:

> Your rights are
>   1 - Not to be tested without your free and informed consent
>   2 - To refuse to take the test. If you do this you application will be denied.

I am not really interested in having the tests done, but I am required to have the insurance and am thus **required** to have the test done. Doesn't this mean that I cannot give my free consent and am, in fact being coerced into giving consent?

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Comment: South Africa.
Although answers in other jurisdictions are also fine

Comment: I really don't know the answer, but I suspect that it boils down to the question of whether your employer can require the insurance as a condition of employment.  After all, you can always leave the job if you don't want the test.  Some companies have a clear need to require certain employees to submit to medical tests (airline pilots, for example), while most probably do not.  An airline pilot who withholds consent to required tests can reasonably be fired.  Is the requirement to carry the insurance reasonable in light of the job?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, [informed consent within the context of medicine](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3307558/) is applied from three points-of-view: legal, ethical, administrative. As a whole, generally, informed consent discussions include four needed parts:

1. decision-maker, typically the patient or her guardian/person with power of attorney with capacity to make decisions
2. physician disclosure with enough info to allow the decision-maker to make an informed choice.
3. demonstration by decision-maker that she understands the info.
4. a freely-given authorization of the treatment plan by the decision-maker.

Whether or not your employer may require a certain insurance or whether or not you live within a certain area that allows you to forego certain tests is not of concern to the concept in #4. You still quite clearly have both the opportunity to understand the procedure that will be performed and the ability to make a choice about whether or not you have them perform that procedure.

Comment: The document you link to is about consent to *clinical treatment*. This questions is not about *treatment* but whether to consent medical *tests* in order to get full insurance cover. (Presumably, if certain tests are bad, full cover will not be given.)

Comment: There’s no distinction there. The question is about informed consent in the realm of healthcare and the law.

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't this mean that I cannot give my free consent and am, in fact being coerced into giving consent?

I do not know about the law in South Africa, but under EU law: Yes, this would be interpreted as you being coerced into giving consent.

This follows from the [GDPR Receital 43](https://gdpr-info.eu/recitals/no-43/). Here is the relevant part:

> Consent is presumed not to be freely given if [...]  if the performance of a contract, including the provision of a service, is dependent on the consent despite such consent not being necessary for such performance.

Here "necessary" specifically means "necessary for performing the service" *not* "necessary for the commercial purposes of the controller".

In your case, the tests are not in any way *necessary* for providing you with insurance. The *only* reasons for the tests is to protect the commercial interests of the company.  Presumably, if you consent to the tests, and they show that providing you with full coverage would be a financial risk for the company, you will be denied full coverage.

I.e.: Given the GDRP definition of freely given consent, it pretty obvious that this description of your rights:

> Your rights are [...]
>   To refuse to take the test. If you do this you application will be denied.

invalidates any pretense of consent being freely given.

The premise that lies at the root of this question is a very interesting one, that AFAIK is handled different in different jurisdictions.

In the country I live, the majority think that it is politically desirable that all citizens have full coverage, pay the same, and that pre-existing conditions should not exclude anyone from full coverage. This means that insurance companies *cannot* use the refusal to undergo tests, or refusal to fill in self-declaration questionnaires as grounds to deny someone full coverage, or to charge higher premiums. (In other countries, such as the USA, the majority view is different).

**Notice**: The GDPR only apply in Europe.  If the definition of "freely given consent" is South Africa is different, this may be of no practical use to you.

Comment: How is consent as defined by the GDPR relevant to consent for a medical procedure?  The GDPR presumption regarding free consent would apply to any consent given with respect to the data generated by the test, but it would not apply to the consent to have the test performed in the first place.

Comment: My understanding is that the test in question for all practical purposes is about getting *data* about the data subject's health. To me, that means that the GDPR's defintion of "freely given consent" is relevant. ...

Comment: ... Let's instead apply the definition offered by A.fm. in his/her answer. This definition basically says that "freely given" means that you're told the facts and then are free to decide, as long as you know what the consequences are. In this case, saying "yes" means that any preexisting condition will be exposed (so if they are present you will be denied coverage), and saying "no" means that your application will be denied (so you will be denied coverage). It is this type of Catch-22 situations the GDPR is supposed to prevent.

Comment: But isn't the real point that the coverage is a requirement to keep the job?  Doesn't your reading of the GDPR imply that no employer in Europe can require medical tests as a condition of employment?

Comment: "Let's instead apply the definition offered by A.fm. in his/her answer. This definition basically says that "freely given" means that you're told the facts and then are free to decide, as long as you know what the consequences are."  Yes, @FreeRadical, precisely. phoog's comment on the question is the right idea, too. When someone is talking about healthcare and they mention informed consent, they are talking about patients rights and standards the care providers should operate under when performing certain procedures, etc. It's not about online data protection laws.

Comment: Also, OP did not say that he would be denied coverage based on the required tests. This is more likely more along the lines of having to prove you're filling out job applications in order to retain unemployment insurance benefits. I know of certain corporate healthcare plans that have a component like this. Of course, knowing which tests OP finds objectionable could help elucidate this point.

Comment: @phoog. "Doesn't your reading of the GDPR imply that no employer in Europe can require medical tests as a condition of employment?" No. Consent is only one of the conditions for lawfulness of processing. Another one is this: "processing is necessary for compliance with a legal obligation to which the controller is subject". If there is a law that require the employee to meet some medical standards, that law would be the basis for lawfulness of processing, and no consent would be needed. This, for instance, would be the basis for requiring airline pilots to undergo medical tests.

Comment: Ok, but if we're talking about tests that can be justified *without* consent, then the GDPR angle on the employee's consent is irrelevant, since, if the life insurance is a legitimate requirement (it needn't be a legal requirement; it might fall under Article 6(1)(f)), then the employee's consent isn't required for data processing.  Then the only consent that is left is the patients' rights consent.  The EU may define that similarly, but if they do it's in some other legislation.

Comment: @A.fm. I just re-read the document carefully. Depending on the test results I can indeed be denied cover. The tests are also specific to the life insure and is not required for my job (I'm a software developer), however according to my employer I need life cover, though personally I don't see the need.

Comment: Interesting conundrum, indeed. Nonetheless, this is absolutely not a GDPR-related issue.